# SEO - Removing old links from Google

Tags: seo, redirects

I recently switched my company from Opencart 1.5 to Magento 2.
I've created new SEO friendly URLs for the products, and wrote a redirect script in my .htaccess file that works on a majority of the links, but I have about 600 links on which my script isn't working.

Is there a way to do bulk url removal from google that I can use on my entire old url structure, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To be clear, you've redirected some of the links, and other links you're planning to leave as 404. And you want Google to remove these 404'd pages from its index?

Comment: I don't want those 600 links to be 404s. I want to know if it's better to request removal, or to try and write more .htaccess rules. I'm not very good at .htaccess rules, so I'm wondering if it's better to request removal of those links, but I don't know how to bulk request removal (or if it's even possible)

Comment: It's not advisable to request removal of a page on Google unless it is 404 or otherwise inaccessible. Would you mind including more detail in your question, including what links you want to remove from Google and why?

Comment: something like https://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=&product_id=10199 creates a 307, because of a previous redirect